# Three.js TextGeometry Trouble Drawing

Tags: javascript, three.js

I followed the demo code but cannot get TextGeometry to draw.  The font file is present on the server.

```
    var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();

    loader.load( 'fonts/open-sans-regular.js', function ( font ) {

        const textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ffff } )

        const textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry('asdfasdfasdfdsf',
        {
            font: font,
            size: 300,
            height: 200,
            curveSegments: 4,
            material: textMaterial
        }
    )

        textGeometry.translate(20, 50)
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, textMaterial)
        scene.add(mesh)

    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Font.js" ></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="FontLoader.js" ></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="FontUtils.js" ></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="TextGeometry.js" ></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="helvetiker_regular.typeface.js">  
 </script>
```

I'm not sure if it helps.But when I add these file first, I can create 3D text.
This is my code.

```
 var textMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x000000});
 var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry("text",{
    size : 15,
    height: 1,
    curveSegments: 3,
    font: 'helvetiker',
    weight: 'normal',
    bevelThickness: 3,
    bevelSize: 0,
    bevelEnabled: true
  });
  var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(aboutmeGeo,bulletMat);
  textMesh.position.set(x,y,z);
  function createText(){
  scene.add(textMesh);
  }
  function removeText(){
  scene.remove(textMesh);
  }
```

I download FontLoadejs、Fontjs in threejs r80;
FontUtiljs here:
https://github.com/kriffe/threejs-extras.
You can download helvetiker_regulartypefacejs in threejs old version.
I hope my answer can help you.^-^